# List of current logged on users, from list of PCs

Tags: windows, user

From a list of computers (IP address, or hostname), is there a tool I can use to build a list of the currently logged on user for each computer?

I have a tool which can do this but used all computers connected to a domain controller, which covers multiple sites.

I have a specific group of computers at one site I need to run this on (all on the same subnet).

Comment: What OS are these computers?

Comment: :) Sorry, should of specified this.  90% are Windows XP, the rest are Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap [psloggedon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545) in a for loop.